# Add View at top of Recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

In my android application, there is a slideshow at top of page and below it, there is a recycler view, my problem is how to add the slideshow above recycler view in a way that slideshow can be scrolled with recycler view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pattern"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share image what kind of UI do you need?

Comment: Take a nested scrollview as parent and for recycler view  set nested scrolling false

Comment: I'd also go with @Redman's solution

Comment: @Redman not worknig

Comment: It will work for sure , Post what have you done as an edit to question

Answer (score 0):

In my android application, there is a slideshow at top of page and below it, there is a recycler view, my problem is how to add the slideshow above recycler view in a way that slideshow can be scrolled with recycler view.
This is UI
[image: link]

Comment: Edit your question , do not post it as answer